# Databases changed, certain page is not working due to rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My hosting changed my database host name and I am unsure about where a certain file is.

My main website is live but I have a custom CRM and the entry URL is index.php?mid=crmsystem

This site uses ExpressionEngine CMS.

There is a `.htaccess` file with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ ./index.php?mid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I think this translates to is get everything after `mid=` and go to it, but I am not sure.

Can someone explain what it is doing? I looked at the index.php file and there is no logic checking for mid in the query string.

Just trying to find the database connection file to update.

Comment: Your hosting changed your database name without informing or asking you? They can't do that.... who're you hosted with?

Comment: Is your index.php including other php files ? It's maybe not your index.php that checking your URL...

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```

It means your URL should not be a derectory location. If it's true, then execute :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ ./index.php?mid=$1
```

It means watever you have in the URL (characters or numbers) should be taken and past as the value of the GET variable mid. Then you are redirect to the index.php with `$_GET[mid] = whateverURL` ...

`RewriteCond` is used to write if statements in .htaccess.

`%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` check the URL value with !-d

`-d` means directory

`RewriteRule` is a rules aply on a URL

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$` is a regex that math the URL

`./index.php?mid=$1` is where it should be rederect

`$1` is the first element match by the parentheses in the regex

Comment: But the original link is index.php?mid=crmsystem - so what would be the resolved URL?

Comment: @andrewb It should be good because there is a "?", a "." and a "=", that are not match by the regex so, the URL is not redirect

Comment: @andrewb Have you try to do just your.site/crmsystem, because with your htaccess, index.php?mid=crmsystem is useless